# UICollectionView didSelectIotemAt issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that is populated by an array of images. I want to allow the user to tap on an image and preview it in a new `UIViewController`.

For some reason, `didSelectItemAt` method isn't working as expected. It doesn't throw an error, it gets called, just nothing happens really. Not sure what I do wrong here.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("did select item at was called")
    let dashboardStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: STORYBOARD_DASHBOARD, bundle:nil)
    let destinationVC = dashboardStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewPostImageVC") as! PreviewPostImageVC
    destinationVC.selectedImage = arrayOfSelectedImages[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Is self.navigationController `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Allen's comment points at the problem. If you're sure your method is being called (The print statement appears in the console) then the most likely problem is that `self.navigationController` is nil. With the optional chaining you're using, that call will fail silently if it's nil, which may or may not be what you want. Try changing it like this:

```
guard let navController = self.navigationController else {
  print("Navigation Controller is nil!")
  return
}
navController.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: You're right. It is nil. The `PreviewPostImageVC ` is not embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Does it need to be embedded?

Comment: In order to do a push onto a navigation controller the way you're trying to do it, the collection view needs to be in a navigation controller. Alternatively, you can simply `self.present(_:animated:completion:)` to do a modal presentation instead.

Comment: Allen answered. Yes, it must be embedded in a navigation controller in order to do a push. If you're not using a navigation controller then using a modal presentation is a good option.

Comment: @AllenHumphreys - thank you, Allen. I used the alternative because my `UIViewController` wasn't wrapped in a navigation controller!